# Is that an elliptical orbit gas giant?

Tags: atmosphere, orbital-mechanics, gas-giants, seasons

Let's say there was a ship that went into orbit around a gas giant roughly the size of Jupiter. It's going to have a highly elliptical orbit so it's much closer to the sun during summer than in winter (not sure the exact distance). I need to know how I can hint at this to the audience. I already have a habitable moon which is entering spring and all the ice is melting. I want something for the gas giant that could be seen from orbit. Would the color be changing? Would more storms be appearing or just getting bigger?

Comment: How much is the axial tilt? Jupiter is just 3° with respect to its orbital plane but you need more than this to get any seasons.

Comment: @user6760 I think the seasons in the question are meant to be caused by the change in distance to the star since the orbit is highly elliptical, and the entire planet changes to get warmer/cooler at the same time.   Moons with high axial tilts might be weird, say in the part of the orbit where you are closest to the star the northern hemisphere is pointing towards the star.   In that case the northern hemisphere would have really harsh summers and winters, and the southern hemisphere would have mild summers (star low in the sky when closest) and winters (star high in the sky when furthest)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This gives me a nice opportunity to talk about one of my favorite subjects: Uranus.

You see  Uranus may be relatively small (it's not quite as big as Jupiter), but due to its size category it can still serve as a good model for planetary weather. Uranus is very far from the Sun , and its orbit its not very eccentric... But due to it being so tilted it still gets some huge seasonal variations on its weather.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranus)

> For a short period from March to May 2004, large clouds appeared in the Uranian atmosphere, giving it a Neptune-like appearance. Observations included record-breaking wind speeds of 820 km/h (510 mph) and a persistent thunderstorm referred to as "Fourth of July fireworks".
> (...)
> Near the summer and winter solstices, Uranus's hemispheres lie alternately either in full glare of the Sun's rays or facing deep space. The brightening of the sunlit hemisphere is thought to result from the local thickening of the methane clouds and haze layers located in the troposphere. The bright collar at −45° latitude is also connected with methane clouds. Other changes in the southern polar region can be explained by changes in the lower cloud layers. The variation of the microwave emission from Uranus is probably caused by changes in the deep tropospheric circulation, because thick polar clouds and haze may inhibit convection. Now that the spring and autumn equinoxes are arriving on Uranus, the dynamics are changing and convection can occur again.

To be honest: Jupiter, Uranus and your planet are all balls of gas. You heat gas, it moves faster. Sure, there are many other complex physic things going on and sometimes stuff happens that makes no sense or that you can explain. But if you just say that during summer the gas giant's clouds get brighter and faster and leave it at that, you're good.

People who don't understand climatology will not think too much about it, and will be captivated by how cool your worldbuilding and story are. People who do care about climatology will mostly suspend their disbelief.

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

As you orbit around the gas giant while the gas giant gets closer to the central star, that will give two surely visible effects:

1. the apparent size of the star in the sky will increase, and more eccentric the orbit is, the more evident will the effect be. For a reference, this is [what the Sun size looks like at aphelia and perihelia of the planets of our solar system](https://www.skymarvels.com/infopages/vids/Sun%20-%20Apparent%20Size%20from%20the%20Planets.htm).

[image]

2. the luminosity of the planet face exposed to the star will increase. Remember that the radiation intensity scales with the inverse square of the distance, so halving the distance from the star would increase the luminosity of the surface by a factor 4.

You can describe the whole things as "their sun was slowly and steadily getting bigger and hotter, and the planet surface was shining brighter under it".

Answer (score 3):

**Can we lose a little atmosphere to solve the problem?**

We'd need @HDE226868 to confirm this, but might it not be possible that an orbit sufficiently close to the star might leave a trail of gaseous atmosphere? Even if this isn't entirely mathematically sound (we don't want your habitable moon burnt to a crisp...), the fact that your gas giant and star would be orbiting a barycenter means you'd get a lovely Spirograph-looking trail of debris or, perhaps, an unusually dense cloud of debris inside the orbit of the gas giant.

The trail or cloud I'm talking about could be as obvious or subtle as you desire. If you don't want it to be too obvious (i.e., it's discovered later in the story), then make the density insufficient for visual detection, but sufficient for (e.g.) spectrographic or reflective detection. Think, "there's light bouncing off stuff that shouldn't be there." Your travelers must investigate to discover the spiral of debris or the unusual cloud and, therefore, conclude the highly elliptical orbit.

Comment: Less dramatic of an effect, but also came to mind... if the orbit is very eccentric, then the clash between solar winds and magnetosphere will lead to tremendous seasonal variation in auroras. They will be stronger and reach lower latitudes during summer.

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw  Ooooh, I like that one.